# Best way to store multiple users's data in android application

Tags: android, xml

I'm quite new to android and I'm trying to build an application where userss can create multiple settings profile and store them in the internal storage. Sinse the data being stored are settings, I was thincking to store them in xml file and creating a different xml file for each profile.
In example:
profile1.xml
profile2.xml
etc...

Is it a good idea?
How can I create those xml files in the internal memory and write each setting in them?

I've seen something like

```
String FILENAME = "profile1";
String setting1 = "set";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(setting1.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

but how can I specify that the file created is in xml format? And how can I create the setting corresponding tags(to parse them later by id for example)?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Alessandro

Comment: use shared preferences. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared preferences, its format is xml, its quite easy to access it, modify/read and should be quite straightforward to implement.

Here is an example that might help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Here are storage options explained http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Hi mate, this solution is optimal also if I need to have different sets of data to store? For example: set1:{property1: value 1, property2: value 2,.... }, set2:{property1: value 1, property2: value 2,.... }? It will be easy to get a lit of stored "sets" of property?

Comment: Sure, just write your own system of adding unique keys for key-value pars.(this is the way you store data in shared preferences). I dont think you can have nested elements in shared preferences xml(check if there is), but you can easily overcome it.  if you have 3 users for ex. write in xml, numOfUsers : 3 for you reference , and make the keys for property's go like property1+userNum, property2+userNum etc...